# LibGDX displays black screen while app is paused but still visible (e.g. during in-app purchase password dialog) on iOS

Tags: ios, libgdx

I converted one of my apps over to LibGDX.

In the earlier version, when I launch an in-app purchase and iOS shows the dialog to ask the user for their password, my app would stay visible and running (animations would update) in the background behind the dialog.

After the switch to LibGDX (and no other changes regarding purchasing), the app now disappears and the background behind the password dialog is just black. Right before this happens, LibGDX reports `[debug] IOSApplication: paused` and right when my app comes back to life, I get the message `[debug] IOSApplication: resumed`.

Is there any way to have LibGDX keep updating my app's screen while it's paused (preferably only if it is still partially visible, though), or at least keep displaying the last drawn frame rather than switching to black?

PS: I have continuous rendering turned off.

Comment: It does. Probably something with your code that's causing that. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Xoppa Maybe it's a bug in the version I'm using (1.6.1 with RoboVM 1.5)... Can you be a little more specific about what exactly you'd like me to take away from the link you posted? My pause() and resume() methods are empty and otherwise nothing graphics-related happens in my code when I launch the In-App purchase. And I doubt it makes sense to post over 10,000 lines of code here if the problem could be anywhere, especially since I'm pretty sure that it's not in my code. But let me add one extra little detail that might make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to fix the problem: Get rid of LibGDX.

Here's how: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35094695/1217178

*Disclaimer:
Clearly this isn't a true answer to the original question, but unfortunately I don't have the time to go hunting for bugs in libGDX, especially since my app is almost 1MB (15%) smaller and starts faster without it, too. But if someone else comes across this issue and figures it out, please do post your answer and I will accept it instead of this one.*